# wp_ prefix changed. What is the way to change so any prefix is understood?

Tags: plugin-development

I have a plugin with a line calling wp_capabilities. This works with the default prefix. If someone changes the prefix to something else (bluehost scripts do this), how do I fix this code? Can you also explain why?

I can hard code it for the individual site but how do I make it 'universal'?

Change:

```
$current_user->data->wp_capabilities[$role_name];
```

To:

```
$current_user->data->wp_xyz_capabilities[$role_name];
```

I understand (and use) {$wpdb->prefix} in an SQL statement works fine.

I've looked at $table_prefix as well as $wpdb->prefix but the combinations I've tried in PHPStorm state expecting semicolons or red lines appear stating there is a problem.

Thank you for your time and explanation.

Comment: Change $table_prefix  = 'wp_'; in your wp-config.php file?

Comment: If there are red lines indicating there is a problem - you must know what the actual problem is. Else it's hard to give you feedback on that issue.

Comment: I'm trying to make the one line universal - regardless of the prefix. currently that line hard codes wp_ and it needs to be changed so the plugin can be installed if any user has changed their prefix. All code I've tried leads to object errors - thus asking here - how can that line be changed.

Answer (score 1):

The prefix refers **only** to the database tables prefix, other uses of the `wp_` prefix in function, class, variable, (array) index or (class) property names are entirely unaffected and remain as `wp_`.

As such, so long as all plug-ins (and themes) you use avoid using SQL statements with a hardcoded `wp_` prefix (and, as you point out, use `$wpdb->prefix`) you will be fine.

It's impossible to comment on what PHPStorm is flagging up, but it will be entirely unrelated to the change of table prefix.

Comment: Thank you but the key to my question is how to make the line of code universal, without hard coding wp_ . I mentioned phpstorm to explain I've tried things but failed. the focus is that line of code - not SQL, wp_config or other things people write about. I have not seen an answer on making the plugins php universal when someone changes the prefix.

Comment: Please reread my answer. The table prefix does not change the `wp_` prefix of function names, array indices, class properties and the like. They are hardcoded. You can't, and you don't need to, change these to make your code universal. Also I don't think there is a `wp_capabilities` property of `$current_user->data`. Even if there was `current_user->data->wp_capabilities[$role_name];` doesn't make sense. What are you trying to get?

Comment: When I say "hard coded" ... I mean `wp_capabilities` and not `anyprefix_capabilities` . Yes, my code works for anyone with a prefix of wp_. Instead, last night someone installed the plugin and I had to change `wp_capabilities` to `theirprefix_capabilities` in that line to get the role written to the database properly. Isn't there a way to write `{$wpdb->prefix}capabilities` but not toss an object error?

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
$current_user->data->wp_capabilities[$role_name];
```

`wp_capabilities` is not a WordPress table or prefix. So please keep it as it is. When you are use any query for fetch data from table at that time you need to add prefix ( `$wpdb->prefix` ) of table. In your case it's not needed.